# Secure boot interfering with my NVidia GTX 1050Ti graphics driver

Tags: 18.04, secure-boot, nvidia-geforce

My laptop has a GTX graphics card, which had driver related issues while installing Ubuntu (alongside Windows). I had to use the parameter `nouveau.modeset=0` while booting Ubuntu for the first time, and then install the drivers required for my graphics card.

At first, I was having trouble installing those drivers, but after disabling secure boot, everything went on fine.Things were going good until I re-enabled the secure boot from UEFI. After that, Ubuntu booted up fine but it was not able to detect the drivers. (`nvidia-smi` could not communicate with Nvidia drivers). If I booted Ubuntu with secure boot disabled, no problem occurred.

How can I enable secure boot and have my Nvidia drivers working on Ubuntu at the same time?